# Python kivy clock shedule interval updating

Tags: python, kivy, scheduling, clock

I have a problem with changing intervals of clock updates. I need to change the intervals while running the clock. I am still new to the kivy library and it's my first bigger project so I just have a basic understading how it all works.

My initial plan of just changing the value doesnt work. I can see the values changing, but the clock stays the same.

```py
class MainWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.btn, player.clock_interval)

    def reduce_clock_interval(self):
        player.clock_interval -= 1
```

The reduce_clock_interval() function is called later with a button:

```
<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    BoxLayout:     
        BoxLayout:
            BoxLayout:
                Button:    
                    text: "Reduce time"
                    on_press: root.reduce_clock_interval()
```

I have also tried using the Clock.cancel() to stop the current clock and create a new one with new values, but still can't get it to work.

```py
class MainWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        clock = Clock.schedule_interval(self.btn, player.clock_interval)

    def reduce_clock_interval(self):
        player.clock_interval -= 1
        Clock.cancel(MainWindow.__init__.clock)
        clock = Clock.schedule_interval(self.btn, player.clock_interval)
```

Update:

I have made some changes while tinkering with the code in meantime:
-moved the clock_interval to the MainWindow class
-moved reduce_clock_interval function to SecondWindow

Minimal reproducible example:

1 .py

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MainWindow(Screen):
    clock_interval = 5

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.clock = Clock.schedule_interval(self.btn, self.clock_interval)

    def btn(self, *args):
        print(*args)
        print(MainWindow.clock_interval)

class SecondWindow(Screen):

    def reduce_clock_interval(self):
        MainWindow.clock_interval -= 1
        MainWindow.clock.cancel()
        MainWindow.clock = Clock.schedule_interval(MainWindow.btn(), self.clock_interval)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

2  .kv

```
ScreenManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    value: value
    BoxLayout:
        cols: 2
        Button:
            text: "Screen 2"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    BoxLayout:
        cols: 2

        Button:
            text: "update clock"
            on_press: root.reduce_clock_interval()

        Button:
            text: "Screen 1"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
```

Comment: I think my fix might not work doesnt work becouse it cancels one local clock variable and creates it elsewhere. I still cant think of a simple way to fix it tho

Comment: Cancel the clock events and then start them again with the interval you want. Or have the clock events fire every frame, but use counters to only do things on the interval you want.

Comment: I tried to do that (third code box) but I cant get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your edited post, you are trying to access the `clock` as a class attribute, but it is an instance attribute. Here is a corrected version of `reduce_clock_interval()`:

```
def reduce_clock_interval(self):
    main_window = App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('main')
    MainWindow.clock_interval -= 1
    main_window.clock.cancel()
    main_window.clock = Clock.schedule_interval(main_window.btn, MainWindow.clock_interval)
```

Comment: Big thanks, This problem stopped me for over a week

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want by keeping a reference to the `Clock` event like this:

```
class MainWindow(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # save a reference to the event
        self.clock = Clock.schedule_interval(self.btn, player.clock_interval)

    def reduce_clock_interval(self):
        player.clock_interval -= 1
        self.clock.cancel()  # cancel the saved event
        # create a new event
        self.clock = Clock.schedule_interval(self.btn, player.clock_interval)
```

Comment: i must still be missing something. Even if I paste it directly to my code it doesnt update the clock to new values

Comment: I updated the post with the minimal reproducible example